# Unit test jqgrid action

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, jqxgrid

I need to verify that the jqxgrid's 'rowClicked' action gets called using mocha unit tests in EmberJS. I have a grid initialized and can verify that it gets rendered, rows and headers are rendered, but I'm stuck on the rowclick event. I use jQuery to simulate a click on a row like this:

```
this.$('#row0grid_testgrid').trigger('click');
```

My grid code listens for the rowClick event like this:

```
this.grid().on('rowclick', function(evt) {
        // My code here
    });
```

How can I verify that this gets called?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you do something like this - mocking functions?

```
/*** in your unit test ***/
//... get your grid object ...
const gridComponent = ....

// save the original function to assign it later back
const originalOn = gridComponent.on;

// now mock the on function
gridComponent.on = function(actionName, handler){
assert.ok(true, "on() function has been called");

assert.equal(actionName, "rowclick", "the action on which on() function has been triggered is correct");
}

// execute tested context
this.$('#row0grid_testgrid').trigger('click');

// tidy up
gridComponent.on = originalOn;
```

There are few things to mention here: if this works, you will test that `on()` has been called and that it was triggered on correct action 'rowclick'. However, you are still not able to test the part of your code "`// My code here`", within evented function.

If you want to test your evented function, what you can do is to call anonymous function from it. Let me show you what I mean:

```
/*** your component code ***/
// this will be called on "rowclick"
myComponentFunction: function(whatArgument){
  // My code here
}

....
const self = this;
this.grid().on('rowclick', function(evt) {
        // instead of pure code call a function
        const someParameters = "foo";
        self.myComponentFunction(someParameters);    
});
...
```

In your unit test you are then able to mock also `myComponentFunction`:

```
// same unit test
....
const originalMyComponentFunction = gridComponent.myComponentFunction;

gridComponent.myComponentFunction = function(arg){
assert.ok(true, "myComponentFunction() has been called!");

// test argument, whatever
assert.equal(arg, "foo", "argument passed to myComponentFunction() from an event triggered on 'rowclick' is correct");
}

// tidy up myComponentFunction mock, too.
gridComponent.myComponentFunction = originalMyComponentFunction;
```

Btw, prefered way to set up mocks and tidy them up are to put it into beforeEach() and afterEach(), look at the [ember-cli testing guides](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#testing).

If you have any better idea how to test this, I would like to learn from you, too :)

Comment: Thanks! The mock works just fine. I don't need to test the function itself, but I'll keep this mind if I need.